# PHP create jpg image of part of page

Tags: php, javascript, jpeg

I will create a dynamic page with content added and rearranged by JavaScript. Is it possible to create a jpg image of this content? - let's say, everything that is inside the container div will be generated to an image. If so, could anyone give me some good tips of this technique?

Answer (score 1):

The traditional method is to run a "headless browser" on your server, "browse" to that url, and take a screenshot. It can be done to some accuracy on the client side in HTML5 browser, see this discussion:

[Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

Answer (score 1):

This question may help:
[Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

and then this one:
[convert canvas to jpeg image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416616/convert-canvas-to-jpeg-image)

The sequence of your algorithm would be something like:

1. create screenshot using canvas
2. convert the canvas screenshot to a
   JPG file